# firebase.auth is not a function when dispatching login action

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-firebase, react-redux-firebase

I'm trying to connect redux and firebase using react-redux-firebase (3.x.x) and react-native-firebase v6 modules. I'm following documentation and examples from [react-redux-firebase docs](https://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/integrations/react-native.html), considering their [v3 migration guide](https://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/v3-migration-guide.html), but it seems i just can't get it to work. When i dispatch following login action I get the error:
`TypeError: firebase.auth is not a function`

Firebase app is natively initialised and when I create store I use HOC [ReactReduxFirebaseProvider](https://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/api/ReactReduxFirebaseProvider.html). Has anyone already had a similar case?

I tried to manually initialize firebase app but i guess this is not the case for my problem as i get warning that default app is already initialized.

Thanks in advance.

```
export const login = credentials => {
  return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase}) => {
    const firebase = getFirebase();
    // console.log(firebase);      <-- here i control firebase instance and it seems ok
    firebase
      .login(credentials)          <-- error is thrown
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({type: LOGIN_SUCCESS});
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch({type: LOGIN_ERROR, err});
      });

    // OR
    // doesn't work either, throws the same error
    /* firebase
      .auth()                     <-- error is thrown
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(credentials.email, credentials.password)
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({type: LOGIN_SUCCESS});
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch({type: LOGIN_ERROR, err});
      }); */
  };
};

// It should return a promise instead of an error.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
...
onLogin = async (user, success_callback, failed_callback) => {
    await firebase.auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
        .then(success_callback, failed_callback);
}
```

worked for me

Comment: I see you're using `firebase` package instead of `react-native-firebase v6.x.x`. After I posted my question I first switched to `react-native-firebase v5.x.x` and error still occurred. Then i tried Google's original `firebase` package too and it seems it works for now. One can imply that it is possible to make it work at first based on existing `react-redux-firebase` documentation. But then i ran into a wall, unfortunately. I think it has to do with not up-to-date instructions for newer version. Thanks for the advice.